# Download and open PDF file from Salesforce Site Aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, force.com-sites, pdf

This is from another question 'Render PDF from Aura Component on a Salesforce Site' which was not resolved.  I need to render an existing pdf(editable) file.  So when the user clicks the link they can edit the pdf. The aura component is used on a Salesforce site.  So instead of opening an editable pdf file on click.  Would it be possible to download the file and and then open the file when the user clicks the link? I am assuming if its downloaded and then opened the pdf would editable.

Comment: Could you please make it clearer about what you want to do in the Aura component? If you want to print the data that you displayed on the component, you can do it via `window.print()`. If it is a data got from a record, you can consider using the Visualforce PDF feature

Comment: I have an editable pdf that I am trying to use on a public SF Site.  The pdf is being referenced inside an aura component. Currently if I click on the link it opens the file.  The only way to allow the user to edit the pdf is to download the file and reopen it.  I am just trying to reduce the number of clicks and give a good user experience.  So trying to see if there is a way to have the file automatically download and then open when the user clicks the link.

Comment: It seems it's controlled by the user's browser only. For instance, Firefox allows the user to choose whether to open the file or download it.